# Filtering a column in a formula and correcting formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Two part question.

I have a formula in excel that currently doesn't work, and so I want to correct this formula and then apply it to a subset of rows that I want to be able to select within a formula.

Here is a screenshot of what I am working with:

[image: Excel Screen Shot]

**Part 1**:

So the result is being calculated in cell G3. I would have expected the value to return the value 5 and not 6 as what I expect the calculation to do is the following:

1) Look in column C and find which rows are less than the threshold value in cell G3.

2) Of those rows that meet that criteria, return the values that are in column B.

3) Take the max value of those returned values which is 5.

**Am I missing something here?**

**Part 2**:

Second part of the question is that I would like to be able to apply the "correct" formula in Part 1 to a subset of rows based on the the ID's in columns A. Basically I would like to take the unique ID in cell E3 and then apply my corrected formula to all of the rows where the values in column A matches E3. This one I cannot seem to find a formula for to do.

This excel doc is going to become a general tool and so I don't want to have to select rows manually and so would like to be able to do all of the matching without selecting thins manually.

Comment: Why not `6` the value in C is less than the threshold and the id is `A`, so why does `6` get excluded?

Comment: Change your criteria in the IF from :`C3:C10<=F3` to `(C3:C10<=F3)*(A3:A10=E3)`

Comment: Sorry the formula is correct, I'll actually leave it as is to not confuse someone who may read this. I'll try the formula update

Comment: @ScottCraner it works, thanks!!!!!

Comment: @ScottCraner if I want to add more conditions to filter by, i.e., rows to select, do I just keep adding the conditional statement in parathenses and multiplying them? For example if I had another column D with values I wanted to check against where I get that rows that are also greater than 19, could I do something like `(C3:C10<=F3)*(A3:A10=E3)*(D3:D10>19)`?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @ScottCraner is there a command to say return the value when the condition first switches from TRUE to FALSE? For example, if the threshold was 40 and the values in column C were 10, 20, 50, and 5 then I want to return the value corresponding to 20 since it was the last value that was TRUE  as 50 is above the threshold. Using the current logic in my problem it would return the value corresponding to 5 because it is the minimum and that's actually not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a recent version of Excel, you can use `MAXIFS`:

```
=MAXIFS(B3:B10,A3:A10,E3,C3:C10,"<=" & F3)
```

[image]

FYI, based on your description, `6` *is* the correct return value.

Comment: Actually `MAXIFS` is not a function in the version of excel that I have. Could you also explain why 6 is the correct value? Or is it because its returning the row number and not the value in column B?

Comment: @JohnSmith you need to tell us why 6 is not the correct answer.  It meets all the requirements you have stated, 10 is less than 40 and id = 'A' and it is the max value in B.  So why is it the wrong answer here?

Comment: Your screencap looks like it's taken from Excel 2016. What version are you using? `6` is the correct answer because `A7``s value is `"A"`, `C7`'s value is less than `40` and `B7``s value (`6`) is the maximum value that fulfills those requirements (column `A = "A"` and column `C <= 40`

Comment: @ScottCraner you are correct, I'll delete that part of the question.

Comment: License Volume 2016, Version 16.16.7